# Bug Poco::Dynamic::Var for long long

Tags: json, poco-libraries

I'm using poco 1.6.0/1.6.1, gcc 4.8 and have problem with JSON Serialize.

```
Poco::JSON::Object obj;
const long long my_value = 0xFFFFFFFFFF;
obj.set("uid", my_value);
const auto rslt = obj.stringfy(); //in this I have crash
```

I rummaged in the source code, and found that Dynamic::Var::isNumeric,  Dynamic::Var::isInteger returns false value. This behavior is correct, or am I mistaken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `VarHolder<long long>` specialization, so it fails back to [default](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/develop/Foundation/include/Poco/Dynamic/VarHolder.h#L597), which is false. You can write your own specialization or use corresponding POCO typedef-ed [types](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/develop/Foundation/include/Poco/Types.h) for which specialization exists.

Comment: Ok! Maybe in my case it is better to use Poco::UInt64 or Poco::Int64